# Is there a way to get the type of return value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I want to do something like following code excerpt in ruby

```
a = MyClass.new

a.class

#=> MyClass
a.methods

#=> list all available methods for object a or instances methods for MyClass
```

Can I do the similar thing in javascript? and also want to hear suggestion from you any better way available to get the object type and what's methods and property available for the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = new MyClass();
console.log(a.constructor);
// => MyClass
console.log(a.constructor.prototype);
// => [object Object] with methods of that class
// (does not include inherited methods)
```

Comment: this is just what I want, although @benekastah 's way is fancier, but I think it's always good to know what's running under the hood

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#object-functions) for this task.

> Underscore is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a
>   lot of the functional programming support that you would expect in
>   Prototype.js (or Ruby).

The method you are looking for is [`functions`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#object-functions), also aliased as `methods` (the link should take you to it).

```
var a = new MyClass()

a instanceof MyClass // => true
a.constructor === MyClass // => true

_(a).methods() // Lists all methods that are members of a
```

Comment: Good call on underscore.js, there's no need to (poorly) implement this sort of thing yourself.

Comment: underscore.js seems cool and way to go, I will dig into it later